# Why didn't James Bond instruct the Swiss Banker to stop Vesper's cash withdrawal?

Tags: casino-royale

I assume Bond didn't even try to ask Mr. Mendel to stop the wire transfer by Vesper Lynd. Why not? My assumption is reasonable because the movie shows Vesper Lynd walking to Gettier with a gray briefcase. Later Mr. White picks up that gray briefcase.

If I got anything wrong or if anyone wants to add stills from the movie, go ahead and edit this.

[Casino Royale Script - transcript from the screenplay and/or the Daniel Craig James Bond movie](http://www.script-o-rama.com/movie_scripts/a2/casino-royale-script-transcript-craig.html)

> -Hello, M.
> -I got your note. Yes? We'll talk about that later. Right now I have a lovely man from the Treasury here... ...wondering if you're ever going to deposit the winnings. That's a shame. I didn't think they'd miss it. Yes. Well, I told them not to worry. So you'll be depositing it today. On my way to the bank right now. James Bond for Mr. Mendel.
>
> Hello. Mr. Mendel? I'm having trouble accessing the funds in my account.
>
> It was transferred to the account number... ...your company gave us, Mr. Bond. It appears the funds are being withdrawn as we speak.
>
> -Where?
>
> -The Venice branch, of course. St. Mark's Square. Is there a problem, Mr. Bond?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Bond wasn't actually in charge of the account.

Vesper was the one who controlled the finances for the mission. She was the one who gave permission for additional funds to be released.

All Bond could do was arrange for the transfer of the funds TO the account after he won. It was Vesper who was supposed to transfer the funds back to the Treasury.

Comment: thanks. I thought that account was James Bond's because he says "I'm having trouble accessing the funds in my account." Or was James Bond lying?

Comment: He's a spy, so he's not going to announce that he works for a government, hence why Mendel says "your company". Bond appears to have told them that he owns the account and works for (owns?) some business or other.

Comment: But if Bond wasn't in charge of the account, why did M call him asking why he hadn't transferred the winnings yet? Why didn't she call Vesper?